# Vim function to strip owner/repo from Git URL via regex

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to write a vim function that returns just the Owner/Repo component of a full Git(hub) URL.

For example:

```
function! PackInstall(source)
        let short = substitute(a:source, '(?<=\:)(.*?)(?=\.git)', '\1', "")
        echo short      
endfunction
```

In the above example, I expect a 'source' like `git@github.com:vim-airline/vim-airline.git` to return a 'short' value of `vim-airline/vim-airline`. Unfortunately this regex doesn't seem to compile, and 'short' just comes back as the original `git@github.com:vim-airline/vim-airline.git`.

What's the right regex to use in this context, or is there an easier way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks you're trying to use Perl-like regex syntax. But Vim has its own flavor.

A possible solution:

```
function! PackInstall(source)
    return matchstr(a:source, ':\zs.*\ze\.git')
endfunction
```

See also `:h perl-patterns` for an overview of Vim vs. Perl regex differences.